# Multiprocessing and Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing and sockets to allow multiple connections to the same socket. However, I am having a real hard time because I don't have much experience in this field.

The code I have isn't working

```
def server(port, listen=10):
    connected = []
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(listen)

    while True:

        conn, address = s.accept()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=server, args=(port, listen))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        command = raw_input("Command: ")
        conn.send(command)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your port? Check with _netstat -na | grep <your_port_number> that no other process is using that port already.

Comment: No, thats not the problem because when I send data to the client it goes through. Its a multiprocessing problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to create multiple servers in loop. Single server is suffucient for your task, no need to open many listening sockets. Every local port may be bound by at most one listening socket -- that's why you see "address in use" error.

Try out the Python standard [`TCPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example) class, this could be much more convenient than to bother with low-level sockets.

For threading server see [this example](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins).

At the OS socket level, this scheme needs only one listening socket, which will spawn new socket each time when accepting a new connection (that's the standard way of socketry). Then you'll work with new socket at the separate thread (keep in mind access to common data shared among threads).

Comment: Okay, I took the error out because that is not my problem. I took away the error. I just need multiple connections to connect to the same socket using multiprocessing.

Comment: Actually, the multiprocessing docs talk about this. See (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) near "Example where a pool of http servers share a single listening socket".