# Multiple Connections to a Socket Without Threading or Spawning a New Process With Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing

Is it possible to write a server that allows multiple connections without using threads or a new process?

Now I am not talking about a bunch of socket.accepts(), but is there a different way?

Comment: based on your prior question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602579/multiprocessing-and-sockets you'd do well to read an introduction to how sockets are used.

Comment: I have been doing a lot of reading, I am just trying to find the easiest way to do this. I am no expert with sockets by any means. I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have multiple `accept`s you don't have multiple connections so it doesn't matter how you process things that aren't there.

It is possible to handle multiple accepted connections in a single thread using a classical [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) loop.

Answer (score 2):

Python provides the module [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#module-asyncore).
Here is a nice example of an [echo server](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#asyncore-example-basic-echo-server).